# Positioning an image at bottom of screen in bootstrap grid over multiple rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a prototype page to show off a potential design to a client and I keep bumping up against the image that would appear between the side bar and the main body just barely being misaligned. 
It seems to be appearing above the .row of which it SHOULD be a part of but it's just floating above it. You can see this in action live on my prototype (a bit messy right now still need to apply most of the style after the grid is sorted out).
[Here](http://derekgillies.com/LiUNA2/)

The relevant markup starts at line 146:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="general">General Inquiries</div>
        <div class="organiz">Have an organizing tip?</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <img class="featureimg hidden-sm" src="img/feature.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="construction">Construction and Specialized Workers</div>
        <div class="foot2">&copy; 2014 LiUNA! Local 1611 All Rights Reserved</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the style is thus:

```
.featureimg{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: I've gone back through the document and validated the markup and I'm still encountering the same issue unfortunately. The image doesn't really work yet at 1024x768 and is disabled for bootstrap's small and extra small.

If you need clarification on what it SHOULD look like, the PDF design file is on my hosting.

http://derekgillies.com/LiUNA2/Pink%20Hardhat2.pdf

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused, what is supposed to be lining up with what?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the 'featureimg' should be touching the bottom of the page, visible between the footer elements, instead of floating above the foot.

Comment: You have a number of validation errors, especially stray and unclosed tags: see http://bit.ly/1hMngIj . I think you want to start by fixing those. Good luck!

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm a bit of a ditz today, thanks. Been spending too many hours on this for a friday meeting but maybe I need to take a break tonight.

Comment: Breaks are awesome, you would be surprised at how many problems they solve.

Comment: Totally in agreement, it looks like a good night to hit the swimming pool.

Okay I've validated the HTML and all the CSS I can (Bootstrap of course doesn't validate) but the question still stands as to why the image isn't appearing in the right spot.